# Как сделать Двумерный массив с рандомными значениями

Tags: c#, массивы

Необходимо сделать двумерный массив в виде таблицы, количество строк и длину вводит пользователь, а каждый параметр массива - рандомное число,

Неправильный код:

```
static void Zadanie5(int k, int o)
    {
        int[,] mass2 = new int [k,o];
        for(int p =0; p<k ;p++)
        {
            int q = 0;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            q = rnd.Next();
            for (int i = 0; i < k+1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < o; j++)
                {
                    int r = q;
                    Console.Write((mass2[i, j] = r) + "\t");
                    r = q;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Зачем 3 цикла, если массив 2-мерный? )

Answer (score 2):

Вот, держи.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("Ввидете высоту:");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Ведите длину:");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Zadanie5(n, k);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    /// <param name="n">Высота</param>
    /// <param name="k">Длина</param>
    static void Zadanie5(int n, int k)
    {
        var array = new int[n, k];
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j =0; j < k; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] =  random.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Решение:");
                        try
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine("Введите высоту:");
                                int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine("Введите длину:");
                                int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                                Console.WriteLine();
                                Zadanie5(n, k);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR вы ввели данные в неправильном формате, пожалуйста попробуйте снова ;)");
                        }


static void Zadanie5(int n, int k)
    {
        var array = new int[n, k];
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = random.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Конец");
    }
```